# Automatically generate INSERT query from key/value pairs in Python

Tags: python, mysql

How can I automatically create a MySQL insert statement from a Python dict?

```
file_info['filename'] = 'image.jpg'
file_info['size'] = 1682
file_info['id'] = 'a4Fabaz125'
```

Right now, I manually specific each value:

```
query = """INSERT INTO files
           (filename, size, id)
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",
            (file_info['filename'], file_info['size'], file_info['id'])
```

But is there a way to auto-generate the insert statement based on the key-value pairs specified in the first part? This would make it much easier to add additional keys.

Comment: sure, you can use the dict keys as the field names, assuming they have a 1:1 correspondence with the fields in your table.

Answer (score 3):

As long as there is a 1:1 correspondence with the fields in the table as @MarcB said:

```
file_info={}
file_info['filename'] = 'image.jpg'
file_info['size'] = 1682
file_info['id'] = 'a4Fabaz125'

fields = ', '.join(file_info)
values = ', '.join(str(x) for x in file_info.values())
print fields
print values
# size, id, filename
# 1682, a4Fabaz125, image.jpg

query = "INSERT INTO files (" + fields + ") VALUES (" + values + ");"
```